# How to efficiently check if values from a list exist in a list of dict

Tags: python

What I'm trying to do:

I am using a given list to query the DB and finding entries. I also want to track entries that do not exist in the DB. I thought it would be best to compare the initial list to the DB results to find entries that do not exist.

Given a list of entries(SKUs), find the entries that don't exist in a list of dicts.

I am trying to find a more efficient way to do it as this is O(n) due to the first `for` loop. What can I do to make it efficient for a given list of 1000 items for example?

Code:

```
sample_entries= [ 'ABCD', 'A123', '3AC4' ] etc.
sample_dict= [{SKU: 'ABCD', 'Something': 123}, etc.. ]
no_sku = []

for nothing in sample_entries:
    if not any(entry['SKU'] == nothing for entry in sample_dict):
        no_sku.append(nothing)
```

Comment: `no_sku = set(sample_entries).difference(d['SKU'] for d in sample_dict)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently looping all dicts, for each entry. One way to reduce loops is to only loop the dicts and remove the SKU from the list. The remaining entries are the ones that didn't appear in any dict:

```py
no_sku = set(sample_entries)

for d in sample_dict:
    no_sku.discard(d[SKU])
```

At the end of this simple loop, `no_sku` will contain the entries that didn't appear as a value to `SKU` in any dict. If you specifically need it as a list, just convert with `no_sku = list(no_sku)` after the loop.

---

Translating this to pure set operations: we want to subtract the set of `SKU` values of all dicts from the list of entries. This further reduces the above loop to a simple:

```
no_sku = set(sample_entries) - set(d['SKU'] for d in sample_dict)
```

Comment: Thanks forgot about sets and didn't know they can be used this way

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
sample_list = [v.values() for v in sample_dict]
results = set(sample_entries) - set(sample_list)
```

Maybe you have to test and time it.

Comment: This makes no sense, since `sample_list` will be a list of `dict_values` objects. But in any case, the OP only wants to compare the "SKU" values, not *all* of the values.

Comment: ok I think I misunderstood the etc ... parts and data structure. My Bad.